# Dependency Injection for ITokenAcquisition

Tags: .net

How do I setup the Dependency Injection for `ITokenAcquisition`?

In program.cs, I have this error `'TokenAcquisition' is inaccessible due to its protection level`:

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<ITokenAcquisition, TokenAcquisition>();
```

In controller:

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web;

namespace MyNamespace.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [Authorize]
    public class MyController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly ILogger<MyController> _logger;
        private readonly ITokenAcquisition _tokenAcquisition;

        public MyController(ILogger<MyController> logger, ITokenAcquisition tokenAcquisition)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _tokenAcquisition = tokenAcquisition;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
        {
            // Get the access token for the API scope
            string[] scopes = new[] { "api://<client id>/my-scope" };
            string accessToken = await _tokenAcquisition.GetAccessTokenForUserAsync(scopes);

            // Use the access token to make a call to the protected API
            
            return Ok();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot / shouldn't do this by yourself. You need to ensure to have the calls to `EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi` and `AddInMemoryTokenCaches` while configuring Authentication.